# Preset an array

Tags: android, arrays

I set up an array[8]  to store a string conversion. The X will range from 0 to 255. If X is less than 127 (7 bits) it does not write higher bit 0's. So I preset the array[8] to all 0's and the next routine would write only the changed data. Code compiles but the array[] all reads 1's regardless of what x= to.

```
int x = 10;
string=(Integer.toBinaryString(x));                          

int[] array = new int[8];                                    
for (int j=0; j < 7; j++){
     array[j]=0;    
}

for (int i=0; i < string.length(); i++) {
array[i] = Integer.parseInt(string.substring(i,i+1));
}

Log.d("TAG", "Data   " + array[0] + "" + array[1]+ "" + array[2] +
        "" + array[3]+  "" + array[4]+ "" + array[5] + 
        "" + array[6] + "" + array[7]);
```

Comment: you don't need the first for-loop... int-arrays are by default 0

Comment: I tried that first but it crashed. X=10 "1010" so when I tired to view array[4] It crashed, I thought it would be 0.

Comment: is the output of this "Data  10100000" ? or "Data   11111111" ?

Comment: If you **are** going to initialize them to zero, you should at least set `array[7]` also. Your loop doesn't get that far.

Comment: I have executed this and the output is `Data   10100000`

Comment: @Bobby If you used Philipp's answer and it worked for you, please mark it as "accepted" using the check mark next to the answer. It will help future users, and reward Philipp for his contribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    int x = 10;
    String s=(Integer.toBinaryString(x));               

    int[] array = new int[8]; 
    //no need for a loop that sets all values to 0.

    int offset = array.length - s.length();
    //you need this offset because the string may be shorter than the array

    for (int i=0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        array[i + offset] = Integer.parseInt(s.substring(i,i+1));
        //applay the offset here
    }
```

This will produce the follow array for `int = 10`:

```
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]
```